# Break string into columns using Regular Expression

Tags: javascript, regex, pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I am new in regex, i want to break the give string into 6 parts using regular expression. I am using the Pentaho data integration tool (ETL tool)

**Given string:** 1x 3.5 mL SST. 1x 4.0 mL gray cap cryovial.

Note: There are many more string with same format

I want output as:
[image]

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Can we see what you have so far please.

Comment: Even if you're new you must have tried something, right. What? And more input examples wouldn't hurt.

Comment: Actually don't know the reasons, why people down vote this question ?

Comment: Terrible to have only a single given string let alone asking for attempts.

Comment: @DHARMINDER You can read the comments here for downvote(s) in this specific case.

Comment: Because you haven't pasted your code aka attempt!

Comment: I was reading regular expression for while, but still confused how to solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *single* string datum you've given looks like it should match the regex pattern:

```
(\d*)x\s(\d*\.\d*)\smL\s(.*)\.\s(\d*)x\s(\d*\.\d*)\smL\s(.*)\.
```

You can use it with `Regex Evaluation` step:

[image: Regex Evaluation]

Answer (score 1):

Use `split` function and regex [`\. | mL |x`](https://regex101.com/r/8byj1o/1)

```js
var text = '1x 3.5 mL SST. 1x 4.0 mL gray cap cryovial'
arr = text.split(/\. | mL |x /g)

var tb = document.getElementById("table")
//creat row
var tr = document.createElement("tr")

for (s of arr) {
  // create cell
  var td = document.createElement("td")
  var txt = document.createTextNode(s);
  td.appendChild(txt)
  tr.appendChild(td)
}

tb.appendChild(tr);
```

```html
<table id='table' border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Par_Count</th>
    <th>Par_Qty</th> 
    <th>Par_Tube</th>
    <th>Child_Count</th>
    <th>Child_Qty</th>
    <th>Child_Tube</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for ur response, the code is breaking the string as expected. But can we make it in one row? as shown in output ?

Comment: @DHARMINDER You mean as one string?

Comment: Can we make it in separate columns ? with column headings

Comment: @ S.Jovan  Can we make the output separate columns headings ?

Comment: @DHARMINDER  You question was asking about regex, and splitting.  This is what this does.  RegEx has no concept of column headings.  So in this context your now asking a different question.

Comment: @ S.Jovan Sorry for the confusion, almost got the output.