# Pentaho Data Integration - Extract string from string

Tags: regex, pentaho, pdi

I have this string:

Goods: 1 pallet 120x80x100 100KG

This is the regex I would use in Ruby:

```
^Goods: <i>(.*)<br>$
```

This is what I need as the result:

1 pallet 120x80x100 100KG

How do I do it in Pentaho Data Integration?

Comment: I think [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49131833/3832970) can give you a hint.

Comment: Maybe you string is `Goods: <i>1 pallet 120x80x100 100KG</br>` ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a step called 'Split Fields', you will feed the column with this data, and set : as delimeter, in the New Fields area you will declare 2 new columns that will receive the split data. This step works pretty much like a Split String per token.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `Regex Evaluation` step, but this one relies on Java regex which are a bit different than Ruby's. However, in your case, it is the same :

```
^Goods: <i>(.*)<br>$
```

[image: 1]]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same regex in a `[Modified] Java Script [Value]` step:

```
^Goods: <i>(.*)<br>$
```

[image]